# How to change text of perticular TextView in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a text and Button in RecyclerView. Am trying to change the text of TextView onClick. I tried in a way by setting text inside OnBindViewHolder but it didn't work that way and wherever I click the button the text changes of last item of recyclerView instead of perticular position I wanted.

Here is my Adapter class-

```
    TextView textView;
    Button button;
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHl onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.un, parent, false);
        return new viewHl(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHl holder, int position) {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.geTextView().setText("hellow");
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    public class viewHl extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public viewHl(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            button=itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);


        }
        public TextView geTextView()
        {
            return textView;
        }
    }
}




[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlU1M.png
```

Comment: May I know where is your list ?

Comment: I have not added any list yet. Text of all TextView is null by default. But when I click on button it should be changed to "hellow"

Comment: To be more clear please see that image provided in the link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlU1M.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that you are holding a single reference to Button and TextView in the adapter. Instead you need to keep it in view holder, so each item will keep their button and text.

```java
public class viewHl extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;

    public viewHl(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button=itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText("hellow");
            }
        });
    }
}
```